# Converting excel file to csv using python error message

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am converting excel(xlsx) file to CSV using PYTHON and i am getting the following error message.

Code:
    import xlrd
    import csv

```
with xlrd.open_workbook('a_file.xlsx') as wb:
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  # or wb.sheet_by_name('name_of_the_sheet_here')
with open('a_file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in range(sh.nrows):
        c.writerow(sh.row_values(r))
```

Error Message:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\Scripts\1.py", line 9, in c.writerow(sh.row_values(r)) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbd' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Any light on resolving the error?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('a_file.xls', 'Sheet1', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('a_file.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

You can easily use pandas